# How to connect my external drive with my raspberry pi?

Tags: kodi, hard-drive

So im using Kodi on my raspberry pi 2 and I have an external drive with Musik and Videos on it, id like to play on my raspberry. But it doesnt have enough power to use the drive, how can i use it?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely!  What you're going to need, though, is a powered USB hub.  This will provide power to your drive and give you the added benefit of being able to add more drives.